# Cannot set X11 forwarding from a WSL-machine

Tags: ssh, gvim, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sshd, freesshd

I put the following settings into my SSH-enabled **remote machines**, with the hope that I can launch GUI programs through SSH sessions.

```
# These settings shall go to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.
X11Forwarding yes
X11UseLocalhost no
AllowAgentForwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
```

I use Windows 10 machines with Xming and WSL, **locally**. On all local+remote machines, I have set `export DISPLAY=0:0` in my `~/.bashrc`, which matches the default setting for Xming that are running locally.

---

Yet, it does different things depending on the host:

- If the host is a Linux machine, when I use `ssh -X user@host` to connect and then fire `gvim`, the GUI is brought to the local machine and all is well;
- If the host is a WSL-running Windows 10 machine, while
  `ssh -X user@host` does get me access to the command line of the remote machine, `gvim` will instead fire up a GUI session **on the remote machine** instead.

  - If I further close the Xming on the remote Windows 10 machine, Gvim will complain that it `"cannot open display"`. This it the same error message when trying to fire `gvim` on the remote machine *locally*(Remote Desktop Connecting into that machine).
  - On the remote Windows 10 machine, I use this command to *host* the server: `sudo service ssh start`.

**Question**: please advise the proper settings for the Windows 10 machine, so that I can hook up GUI programs via X11. Thx!

---

### More debugging info

Excerpts from `ssh -v -X user@remote_server`:

- From the Linux remote machine:

```
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = C.UTF-8
Welcome to Linux Mint 18.1 Serena (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-53-generic x86_64)
:: >>Linux-remote<< ::~>>echo $DISPLAY  
localhost:12.0
```

After further testing, this number shall increase as I open up new SSH sessions with the Linux remote.

- From the WSL-Windows-10 remote machine:

```
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = C.UTF-8
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-17763-Microsoft x86_64)
:: >>WIn-WSL-Machine<< ::~>>echo $DISPLAY 
0:0
```

Repeated "echo-ing" of the `$DISPLAY` in the SSH session with the remote WSL-Windows machine kept showing the same `0:0`.

PS: I have been testing the X-forwaring on the same local machine, with an Xming server running at local port `0:0`. Such Xming server has been happily accommodating GUI from its "local" Windows WSL shell/system, as well as the Linux machine. It now bugs me that the remote Linux machine should be using a port `localhost:12.0`

[image]

Comment: Remote the `display` export from your login files, and simply `ssh -Y user@remote`

Comment: @ivanivan. Thanks for the `-Y` flag. Yet, how to properly "remote the `display` export from my (local) login files"?

Comment: Sorry, typo.  Should be "remove the `display` export from ..."

Comment: I removed all `export DISPLAY=0:0` lines from my `~/.bashrc` (and `fish.conf`). Nothing changed yet ==> I am restarting the WSL-Windows remote now.

Comment: Restarted the remote WSL-Win machine, and same thing: with the local@remote Xming server running, `gvim` won't throw an error but will drop the GUI window at the remote Windows desktop; shutting down the Xming server running at the remote machine shall leave me with the same error.

Comment: I may have been overcomplicating things per the original post. For now, I have `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` in my `~/.zshrc` and get `xclock` to work both locally (with WSL1) and remotely (with SSH). X410 works perfectly as the "X Server" on the local Windows machine.

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem and I solved it by setting "DISPLAY=localhost:0.0" instead of "DISPLAY=:0.0" in WSL.
Refer to,
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57138/why-does-my-x11-forwarding-attempt-fail-with-connect-tmp-x11-unix-x0-no-such

Answer (score 0):

I've seen lots of examples using `resolv.conf` but it never worked for me.

I set `DISPLAY` in my `.bashrc` as `export DISPLAY="$(/sbin/ip route | awk '/default/ { print $3 }'):0"` and it works perfectly.

I can also now get x11 apps in colour: [SOLVED: x11 apps in WSL/ubuntu are black and white only](https://superuser.com/questions/1575740/solved-x11-apps-in-wsl-ubuntu-are-black-and-white-only)

Note this is with WSL 2, WSL 1 may be different.