# SOLVED: x11 apps in WSL/ubuntu are black and white only

Tags: xorg, windows-subsystem-for-linux

If I run an x11 app (xcalc for example) in VcXsrv under Windows, it is in colour. If I run it under WSL/ubuntu it is black and white only; anyone help me work out why? Thanks.

[WSL on left, Windows on right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WC84.png)

More info following comments.

I have a `config.xlaunch` file in my Window startup folder (courtesy of [https://nickjanetakis.com/](http://NIck%20Janetakis)) with the following:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <XLaunch WindowMode="MultiWindow" ClientMode="NoClient" LocalClient="False" Display="0" LocalProgram="xcalc" RemoteProgram="xterm" RemotePassword="" PrivateKey="" RemoteHost="" RemoteUser="" XDMCPHost="" XDMCPBroadcast="False" XDMCPIndirect="False" Clipboard="True" ClipboardPrimary="True" ExtraParams="" Wgl="True" DisableAC="True" XDMCPTerminate="False"/>`

In my `.bashrc` I have the following to set the display:

`export DISPLAY="$(/sbin/ip route | awk '/default/ { print $3 }'):0"`

It all works (as in the x11 apps are displayed) but when I run an x11 app in Windows, for example xcalc or xclock from the VcXsrv menu they are in colour, but only black and white when I run from command line in WSL/ubuntu.

I'll see if I can check how the x11 apps (installed via apt) were compiled - actually thinking about it, it may be that the x11 apps run via VcXsrv are run with colour options, I'll investigate and let you know.

**Update 06/08/20 20:40**

It looks like the colour is configurable using x11 app defaults, there already exists for example xcalc-color config in the app defaults (`/etc/X11/app-defaults`) but don't yet know how to pass that to the xcalc command, anyone else know?

Comment: What instance or configuration is the VcXsrv example connected to exactly?  How are you running a x11 on WSL2, my understanding is that even with WSl2, you are still required to use something like vcXsrv to accomplish running a program like xcalc within WSL2

Comment: I think it has to do with how it was compiled.  On my system, I see the same black and white xcalc as you do and my system shows OTHER color x11 apps just fine.  If you can see the black and white xcalc.. your VcXsrv is working fine.

Comment: I'll add more info to the question above.

Comment: @mjbatty - Instead of providing the solution in the body of your question you should submit an answer.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, thought I had to wait for 15 reputation - I'll update it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple when you know how :)

After some research I found all you need is to create the following file (or modify if exists) in your WSL home:  `~/.Xdefaults`

Add the following line: `*customization: -color`

Everything works as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is working even in 2021. upvoted. 

Comment: Great, glad it helped - I spent ages trying to figure this out!